# folium limit user to drag the map

Tags: python, folium

I have trouble setting max_lat/min_lat max_lon/min_lon so I can limit the user to scroll around the map.

```
map = folium.Map(location = [41.1227, 20.7999],
                 min_lot=40.876401,
                 max_lot=41.16237,
                 min_lat=20.77199,
                 max_lat=20.85032,
                 tiles = 'CartoDB dark_matter',
                 zoom_start = 13,
                 max_zoom = 18,
                 min_zoom =13,
                 width = '100%',
                 height = '40%',
                 zoom_control=False )
```

Even with everything set, I'm still able to drag around. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to fix the display range is to add `max_bounds=True`. It just seems to limit the latitude. The narrowest interval between the maximum and minimum zoom values may result in a higher load using horizontal scrolling, which may inhibit dragging operations.

```
import folium

map = folium.Map(location = [41.1227, 20.7999],
                 min_lot=40.876401,
                 max_lot=41.16237,
                 min_lat=20.77199,
                 max_lat=20.85032,
                 max_bounds=True,
                 zoom_start = 6,
                 max_zoom = 5,
                 min_zoom =4,
                 width = '100%',
                 height = '100%',
                 zoom_control=False )
# map.fit_bounds([[40.876401,20.77199],[41.16237,20.85032]])
map
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Based on my study of the documentation, I think min_lat, max_lat, etc are not programmable parameters.  The way you control the map range is via the location (center point) and the zoom.

Comment: See [this reference](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html).

Comment: If you look at the reference.  It is clear.  The range of latitude is +/-90 and the range of longitude is +/-180.  These are NOT configurable.  If you look closer at the parameters section you will see that these constants are not configurable parameters.

Comment: The correct way to set the map range is via Folium's fit_bounds api.  I have implemented that and can confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing min_lot and max_lot to min_lon and max_lon respectively. That should stop the infinite horizontal panning.